# Android CAB forcing overflow menu when item is removed

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

In my app i have a CAB appear with four menu items. Two are displayed while the other two are in the overflow menu. In my code one of the items is removed when the user has multiple items in the listview selected. When that item is removed the overflow menu disappears and all three of the remaining items are shown. I would like it to continue to show two items and hide the remaining one in the overflow menu.

Menu Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!--disppears when multiple items selected -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/cabEdit"  
    android:title="Edit"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/cabDel"
    android:title="Delete"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/cabRes"
    android:title="Reset"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>

<!-- should always appear in overflow -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/cabSelAll"  
    android:title="Select All"
    app:showAsAction="never" ></item>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, if you are using `appcompat-v7`, your menu resource XML looks like it will give you what you want. If you are trying to use the native action bar (i.e., you are inheriting from `Activity`, not `ActionBarActivity`), then change `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction` and get rid of the `app` namespace entirely.

Comment: How are you starting your CAB? Via [startSupportActionMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#startSupportActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback))?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using ActionBarActivity and it is not displaying how i would like it to. Upon removing the first item the overflow menu disappears and the last item displays even though it is set to never show.

Comment: @ianhanniballake The cab is started from a multiChoiceModeListener and inflated in onCreateActionMode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [setMultiChoiceModeListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setMultiChoiceModeListener(android.widget.AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener)), you are not using the Support Library version of Contextual Action Bars - your code would only support API11+ devices.

You can replace the `app:showAsAction` with `android:showAsAction` to conform with the requirements of the platform Contextual Action Bars (using `tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"` if you want to suppress the lint error) or switch to [startSupportActionMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#startSupportActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode.Callback)) in response to long clicks on your list items and manage check states yourself.

Comment: Android Studio is giving me an error that when using the appcompat library app:showAsAction must be ysed. The code itself functions fine already however, it is not displaying the way I want it to.

Comment: Yep, when you use AppCompat, you need to use app:showAsAction. However, you aren't using AppCompat if you're using `setMultiChoiceModeListener()`. You can add `tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"` to ignore the error.

Comment: Thanks it worked! It's strange that Android Studio would give that error when it actually works fine.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't have worked fine if you used `startSupportActionMode()` for a pre-API 11 Contextual Action Bar - unfortunately the lint check seems to just look if you have AppCompat at all in your project rather than know that you aren't going to be using AppCompat for just this one menu.